# Jasmine: How to add expectation of a method when there are multiple invocations with different parameters

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a situation in which I need to call a service to get chunks of entities using request parameters. e.g.

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $timeout) {

var chunkSize = 2,
params = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

$scope.invokeMultipleTimes = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i += chunkSize) {
    $scope.printParams(params.slice(i, i+chunkSize))
  }
}

$scope.printParams = function (p) {
  //doSomething
}
});
```

It invokes `$scope.printParams` with different parameters.

```
it('should invoke printParams multiple times', function() {
  spyOn($scope, 'printParams');
  $scope.invokeMultipleTimes();
  expect($scope.printParams).toHaveBeenCalledWith([ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6]);
});
```

Here is the sample test case but is says:
*Expected spy printParams to have been called with [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ] but actual calls were [ [ 1, 2 ] ], [ [ 3, 4 ] ], [ [ 5, 6 ] ].*

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/eV6xtf?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue is that `[1,2] !== [1,2]` because they are different objects.

To solve this jasmine has `jasmine.objectContaining` which can test for similar objects including arrays

So changing the expect to

expect($scope.printParams).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining([ 1, 2 ]));
  expect($scope.printParams).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining([ 3, 4 ]));
  expect($scope.printParams).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining([ 5, 6 ]));

works

https://plnkr.co/edit/KJ3bkFkSUyYl0SbZSRFf?p=preview